# ¿Como actualizar varios campos de una tabla en base a una subconsulta en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Lo que quiero hacer básicamente es, actualizar `precio_preparación` de mi tabla `platillo`, en base al `total` que me arroja mi subconsulta, que se encuentra almacenada en una tabla temporal. Prácticamente lo que arroja mi tabla temporal es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero hacer es que todos los platillos de mi tabla `platillo` que tenga un id similar al de mi tabla temporal, se le actualice el `precio_venta` en base al total de la tabla temporal.

De esta manera tengo creada mi tabla temporal:

```
create temporary table tablaTemporal as (select id_platillo as id_platillo, round(sum(total),2) as total from platillo_insumo where id_platillo in 
                                                                      (select p.id_platillo from platillo p 
                                                                      inner join platillo_insumo pi on p.id_platillo = pi.id_platillo
                                                                      inner join insumo i on pi.id_insumo = i.id_insumo 
                                                                      where i.id_insumo = 1/*_id_insumo*/) group by id_platillo);
```

Y la consulta `update` es asi:

```
update platillo set precio_preparacion = (select id_platillo from tablaTemporal) where id_platillo in (select id_platillo from tablaTemporal);
```

Pero al momento de correr la consulta de `update`, me da el siguiente error:

```
Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 'tablaTemporal'
```

La verdad es que soy una persona relativamente nueva en esto queriendo hacer algo fuera de su alcance, Espero que me puedan ayudar, Gracias.

PD:"Esta fue la única manera que se me ocurrió para hacerlo. Si ustedes tienen una mejor idea, porfavor haganmelo saber".

Comment: porque creas una tabla temporal? las tablas temporales solo viven en el ambito de la conexion que las creo... tu problema puede venir por ahi

Answer (score 1):

Tu cadena de update es incorrecta... analicemos tu SQL

```
update platillo 
set precio_preparacion = (select id_platillo from tablaTemporal) 
where id_platillo in (select id_platillo from tablaTemporal)
```

Tu select le dice a la base de datos, que trate de actualizar la tabla platillo, poniendo como precio, todo lo que le devuelva ese select (que es toda tu tabla temporal). Y despues le das una condicion de busqueda, que dice que tiene que estar, en toda la tabla temporal.

Parece ser que lo que realmente querias era algo asi:

```
update platillo as p
set p.precio_preparacion = (select total from tablaTemporal as t where t.id_platillo = p.id_platillo(*)) 
where p.id_platillo in (select id_platillo from tablaTemporal)
```

(*) como no se el nombre de tu campo en la tabla precio_preparacion, estoy suponiendo que es el mismo. Sustituyelo por el que corresponda.

Comment: Me daba este error al ejecutar tu código: "Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 't'", así que llegue ala conclusión que la tabla temporal me generaba conflicto, al final lo que hice fue basarme en tu código y hacerlo de otra manera.

Answer (score 0):

Al final este fue el código final que resolvió mi problema:

```
update platillo pl set pl.precio_preparacion = (select t.total from (select id_platillo as id_platillo, round(sum(total),2) as total from platillo_insumo where id_platillo in 
                                                                      (select p.id_platillo from platillo p 
                                                                      inner join platillo_insumo pi on p.id_platillo = pi.id_platillo
                                                                      inner join insumo i on pi.id_insumo = i.id_insumo 
                                                                      where i.id_insumo = 1)group by id_platillo) as t where t.id_platillo = pl.id_platillo)
where pl.id_platillo in (select t.id_platillo from (select id_platillo as id_platillo from platillo_insumo where id_platillo in 
                                                                      (select p.id_platillo from platillo p 
                                                                      inner join platillo_insumo pi on p.id_platillo = pi.id_platillo
                                                                      inner join insumo i on pi.id_insumo = i.id_insumo 
                                                                      where i.id_insumo = 1))as t);
```

Al ejecutar el código que anteriormente me proporcionaron:

```
update platillo as p
set p.precio_preparacion = (select total from tablaTemporal as t where t.id_platillo = p.id_platillo(*)) 
where p.id_platillo in (select id_platillo from tablaTemporal)
```

me arrojaba el siguiente error:

```
Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 't'
```

Pienso que la tabla temporal me generaba problema, así que opte por hacerlo de esta forma, basándome en el código que me dieron.
Gracias por su ayuda.